# how to make button responsive for mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

how to make my button responsive. i have a button on the image in the slider. its looking good and working fine in desktop but in the mobile its looking too big and its getting overlapped on the slider radio icons so that read more link button not redirecting to any page

code

```
  <div class="ism-slider" data-play_type="loop" data-interval="3000" id="my-slider">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <img src="ism/image/slides/Editing.png">
     <div class="ism-caption ism-caption-0" style="background-color:#8497b0">
     <a href="editing.aspx" class="myButton">READ MORE</a></div>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

image
[image: button is not responsive]

Comment: check @media tag in css, and adjust font size and button width for the different screen sizes you want.

Comment: In addition to @media tags, you can also use viewport units

Answer (score 0):

Your styles in desktop view here.

```
@media screen and (max-width: windowSize) {
    .myButton{
        width: your button width;
        height: your button height;
    }
}
```

Change windowSize for the size of the window you want to apply the styles inside of the @media query